# How to map two columns to an entity type if type instance is immutable?

Tags: java, jpa, orm

I want to map an entity class `Lecture` to a table `LECTURE` where two columns - `from` and `until` - represent timestamps. I want to map these timestamps to `startInclusive` and `endInclusive` of `org.threeten.extra.Interval`.

I thought of using an @Embeddable or a custom object mapper for this purpose but I am not sure if that works well, because `Interval` is immutable after instantiation.

Can somebody advise a best practice for that?

Comment: Is it a library application? Can `from` and `until` vary for the same `Lecture` ?

Comment: from and until are properties of the Lecture but may change when the Lecture is rescheduled. Many Lectures may have the same from and until yet they do not share state.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you ... although instances of `Interval` are immutable, you can still execute `myLecture.setFrom(instanceOfInterval)` and `myLecture.setUntil(instanceOfInterval)`

Comment: The `Interval` cannot be an embeddable because it does not fulfill the requirements for embeddable objects (see JPA 2.1 spec section 2.5 - does it have a public or protected no-arg constructor? it is final!). You cannot use a converter because that maps from **1** column to an object (you want 2 columns to 1 object). You can however create a getter/setter that transforms the 2 persistent properties to/from an `Interval`.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Thank you, I ruled out the first two approaches myself. You suggest using getters/setters so that implies using `AccessType.PROPERTY`, correct? Fair enough, yet I hoped for some solution where I can ise `AccessType.FIELD` which is my favorite. Yet I find that is impossible because of the mentioned reasons, thank you again for pointing those out.

Comment: @JimHawkins I intend to have a single `Interval`instance in my `Lecture` instead of having the interval represented by two attributes which are loosely coupled. I could write a mutable `@Embeddable Interval`myself instead but for some reason I really like to use the library class.

Comment: *[...]implies using `AccessType.PROPERTY`*: No, on the contrary leave it to `FIELD`! There will be two fields, mapped as normal to the DB: `@Temporal(TIMESTAMP) private Date from;` and `until`. These fields do *NOT* have to have accessors (although it doesn't hurt either). Then the getter is like: `public Interval getInterval() { return Interval.of(from.toInstant(), until.toInstant()); }`.